# Sampling with a variable number number of picks

Tags: sampling, weighted-sampling

Imagine we have N items and some weights w for each item, we first draw a random integer s (fom uniform) $s \sim int(U(1, N))$ and then we sample s items according to weights w (no replacement).

`np.random.choice(N, size=s, p=w, replace=False)`

If I do this a 1000 times, I will find that my eventual distribution w* of having chosen each item will not converge to w.

Example N = 3, w = [.5, .3, .2], simulations = 1000

This example will give me less than 50% for the first item to be chosen (counted as total times this appeared in all samples).

How do I need to change input w to get the desired distribution w* (output)?

Comment: If I understood your question, you cannot. There is probability 1/N that you draw all elements in your set. In your example, you draw 3 out of 3 elements in 1/3 cases. Therefore, the lowest probability of any element being drawn is 1/3 regardless its weight w.

Comment: Could be wrong but I think the issue you have is that you are selecting s of N items without replacement. Having said that your question is quite ambiguous. For example you ask how to change w to get the desired distribution, what distribution? Surely w is the distribution ? It might help just to be more clear about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: gowerc, w is the input and the desired distribution, currently occurences will not converge to w

Comment: It's unclear how one uses weights to sample without replacement, because there are several reasonable but inequivalent ways to do this.  Could you be more specific about your sampling method?  It's also not clear what you mean by "eventual distribution of having chosen each item," because it *sounds* like you mean the limiting frequency with which each item appears in a sample, but there isn't any apparent reason why that should equal the weight.  In fact, it ought to be much greater than the weight.  Could you clarify that, too?

Comment: whuber, I have edited the question, hopefully it helps, maybe easier to say what does w need to be so I get [.5, .3, .2] in the end

Comment: The answer is a little complicated and comes down to exactly how `np.random.choice` works.  To get a sense of the issue, *don't* choose random-size samples.  First, generate samples of size $1$ to verify the frequencies are what you expect.  Then, generate samples of size $2$ and tabulate the results: you will discover the frequencies are *not* what you expect.  Then generate samples of size $N$ (still without replacement!) and do the same thing.  The problem with your question ought to become apparent: you might be asking for an impossibility.